# minimax algorithm (connect 4) stalling indefinitely

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, minimax

I am currently attempting to make a minimax algorithm for connect 4 (6x7 board) in Python. I already made a similarly structured function for tic-tac-toe that works fine but whenever I run the connect four minimax method my computer stalls for a minute or two before I kill the function. I know alpha-beta pruning is supposed to make minimax work better but I want to master minimax before implementing pruning. Is it a problem with my code, or do  I have to implement alpha-beta pruning for it to work?

Note: I've already tested the boardWin and MakeMove methods so I'm pretty sure its not that

```
import math
class reproduce_mm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.evals = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "] #stores minimax values for each move calculated by minimax
    def minimax_c4(self, board, computer, move): #minimax algo
        #inputs: board = 6x7 2d array with x's and o's, computer = x or o, move = whose turn it is (x or o)
        player = "o" if computer == "x" else "x"
        next = "o" if move == "x" else "x"
        count = 1 #count is number of free spaces left in c4 board + 1
        for x in range(len(board)):
            for y in range(len(board[x])):
                if (board[x][y] == None):
                    count = count + 1
        for column in range(len(board[0])):
            if (self.emptyCol(board, column) ==  False):
                self.evals[column] = 0
        winner = self.boardWin(board)
        if (winner == computer): #return -count if winner, -count if loser
            return count
        elif (winner == player):
            return count * -1
        elif (winner == "draw"):
            return 0
        else:
            for eval in range(len(self.evals)):
                if (self.evals[eval] == 0):
                    temp = board.copy()
                    temp = self.makeMove(temp, move, eval)
                    self.evals[eval] = self.minimax_c4(temp, computer, next)
                    self.clearBoard(eval, board) 
                    #clears board of previous move in temp (Tried copy.deepcopy but not sure if it works)

            if (move == computer):
                max_val = -math.inf
                for eval in range(len(self.evals)):
                    if (self.evals[eval] != " "):
                        if (self.evals[eval] > max_val):
                            max_val = self.evals[eval]
                return max_val
            if (move == player):
                min = math.inf
                for eval in range(len(self.evals)):
                    if (self.evals[eval] != " "):
                        if (self.evals[eval] < min):
                            min = self.evals[eval]
                return min
    
    def clearBoard(self, c, board):
        for r in range(len(board)):
            if (board[r][c] != None):
                board[r][c] = None
                return
        return
            
    def makeMove(self, board, move, c):
        first = True
        while (first == True):
            for r in reversed(range(len(board))):
                if (first == True):
                    if (board[r][c] == None):
                        board[r][c] = move
                        first = False
        return board
    
    def emptyCol(self, board, c):
        full = True
        for r in reversed(range(len(board))):
            if (board[r][c] == None):
                full = False
        return full
    
    def chooseMove(self): #chooses move by looking at max value from self.evals
        max = None
        index = None
        for ev in range(len(self.evals)):
            if (self.evals[ev] != " "):
                if (max == None):
                    max = self.evals[ev]
                    index = ev
                elif (max != None):
                    if (ev > max):
                        max = self.evals[ev]
                        index = ev
        
        return index
    
    def boardWin(self, board):
        full_board = True
        winner = None
        switched = [[None]*6 for _ in range(7)]
        for r in range(len(switched)): # flips board sideways to check if columns are 3 in a row
            for c in range(len(switched[r])):
                switched[r][c] = board[c][r]

        for row in range(len(board)):
            for item in board[row]:
                if (item == None):
                    full_board = False
                    
        for x1 in range(len(board)):
            if (self.across_win(board[x1]) != None):
                winner = self.across_win(board[x1])
                return winner
            for y1 in range(len(board[x1])):
                if (self.diag_win(board, x1, y1) != None):
                    winner = self.diag_win(board, x1, y1)
                    return winner
        for x2 in range(len(switched)):
            if (self.across_win(switched[x2]) != None):
                winner = self.across_win(switched[x2])
                return winner
            
        if (full_board == True and winner == None):
            return "draw"
        
        return None

    def across_win(self, row, counter = 0, winner = ""):
        if (counter == 4):
            return winner
        elif (len(row) == 0):
            return None
        elif (counter == 0):
            if (row[0] != None):
                winner = row[0]
                counter = counter + 1
            return self.across_win(row[1 : len(row)], counter, winner)
        else:
            if (row[0] == winner):
                counter = counter + 1
                return self.across_win(row[1 : len(row)], counter, winner)
            else:
                if (row[0] != None):
                    return self.across_win(row[1 : len(row)], counter = 1, winner = row[0])
                else:
                    return self.across_win(row[1 : len(row)], counter = 0, winner = "")

    def diag_win(self, board, r, c):
        if (r < 3 and c < 4):
            if (board[r][c] != None):
                if (board[r][c] == board[r + 1][c + 1] == board[r + 2][c + 2] == board[r + 3][c + 3]):
                        return str(board[r][c])
        if (r < 3 and c > 2):
            if (board[r][c] != None):
                if (board[r][c] == board[r + 1][c - 1] == board[r + 2][c - 2] == board[r + 3][c - 3]):
                    return str(board[r][c])
        return None

board = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
         [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
         [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
         ["x", "y", None, None, None, None, None],
         ["x", "x", None, None, None, None, None],
         ["x", "y", "y", "y", None, None, None]]

ai = reproduce_mm()
print(ai.minimax_c4(board, "x", "x"))
ai.makeMove(board, "x", 0)
print(str(ai.chooseMove()))
print(board)
```

Comment: Could you create a runnable example?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Carbon FYI, you can use `[mcve]` to generate that link: [mcve].

Comment: @Carbon I could, but then I would have to add code for checkWin, making a move on the board, etc as well as adding an example. It would probably be around 150 lines total

Comment: 150 lines is probably what you want

Comment: @Carbon thanks, I just edited a a min example into the post. It should run without errors but lmk if something is missing

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There are more than 4 trillion possible connect 4 games, as opposed to mere 255,168 TTT games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a problem with my code, or do I have to implement alpha-beta pruning for it to work?

It is a problem with the number of game states that you want to evaluate. Your minimax function is designed to keep playing moves, recursing until the end of the game is reached and so *all possible* ([4,531,985,219,092](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301106/341715)) games are played: even worse, as the same game states are visited multiple times by exchange of moves (`1. e1 d1 2. c1` leads to the same state as `1. c1 d1 2. e1`), your code actually intends to visit an astronomically larger number of end states.

Here are some measures you can take to improve:

- Set a maximum depth to your recursion. When it is reached evaluate the board without playing more moves: this would be a heuristic that "guesses" what a good estimated value would be (think of counting the number of 3-in-a-rows that can still become 4, recognise winning patterns, ...).
- Use memoization to see if you have evaluated a game state before, so to avoid doing the same job again. Think of an efficient way to identify a game state uniquely (think in terms of bits and column heights). Also realise that the result of the game is the same when you mirror it (left - right), so if you evaluated a game state, also its mirror is evaluated.
- Use an opening database. You can find these online: they list positions with a fixed number of discs (for example: all possible positions after 8 plies) with the theoretical outcome (win, loss, draw). Then make that part of your memoization table.
- The heuristic function could use the concept of *zugzwang* to predict the outcome (like "In this column I will always play on top of the opponent" or "if they play in column A, I'll play in column B, or vice versa", ...): see Victor Allis' thesis: "A Knowledge-based Approach of Connect-Four".
- Alpha-beta pruning: you are right that this can make the search tree narrower, but it isn't the most important optimisation at this point, and wont help much when you don't take any of the other measures.
- Iterative deepening: once you have implemented alpha-beta pruning, its effect will be greater if you visit moves in the order of how good they are. To know how good they are you could first perform the search with a lesser depth, then sort the moves according to that evaluation, and only then do the search with the deeper depth. You can do this iteratively: first search with depth 2, then 4, then 6... You'll have to reset memoization wisely.

There are obviously more techniques than this.